# Trouble with jQuery video plug in

Tags: jquery, video, background

I am trying to use a jQuery plug in for a video background, from this website: http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/

This is how I am sourcing the libraries in my html:

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.imagesloaded.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Nothing seems to be happening when I preview. Am I missing something? Does someone have better instructions for how to use this plug in? THANK YOU!

Comment: What browser and video file type are you using? Not all browsers will play all video types.

Comment: Have you added the code as shown in the `SETUP` area of the plugin's site?